# Can someone explain the output of this recursive function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

This is a function in python3 that prints 1 through 10. There are a few things I don't understand about this, since I'm a programming noob.

This function will subtract 1 from a given number as long as that number is above 1. So if number = 10 it will subtract 1 from 10 to give 9 and then 1 from 9 to give 8 and so on... until it reaches 1, which will be printed to the screen.

I don't understand is why the function subsequently prints 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. Since these numbers are above one, shouldn't they enter the if-statement and then not be printed? According to my understanding of the code, only numbers that are equal to or below 1 will be printed.

In other words: "Why is the output of this function, not "1" alone?"

```
def print_numbers(number): 
    if number > 1: 
        print_numbers(number-1) 
    print(number) 
print_numbers(10)
```

You can try out the code in python to see that the output is 1 through 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling to visualise what actually goes on in a recursive function myself. However, the sequence of events are:

The function is called and a value passed to it. 10 in your example.

10 is then stored in memory
function checks if 10 > 1

and subtracts 1 if true

9 is passed back to the start of the function and is stored in memory. It is positioned after 10, which is still in memory

function checks if 9 > 1
and subtracts 1 if true

8 is then passed back, stored in memory etc

This continues until the remaining value passed back is not > 1

We now have:
10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2

stored in sequence in memory

the function then moves on to the print statement and prints out the numbers starting with the last to be stored in memory i.e. 2

it then discards 2 and moves on to process 3 etc. until it finally prints and discards 10, the first entry in memory.

After trying to figure out what a recusive factorial equation was doing, I found a great visualisation tool that can help to understand what is going on in such equations.

The link is here:

[Python Tutor by Philip Guo](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20print_numbers%28number%29%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20if%20number%20%3E%201%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print_numbers%28number-1%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20print%28number%29%20%0Aprint_numbers%284%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=13&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

I used the value 4 for brevity, but you can edit the code if you want to use any value.

Some coding concepts melt my brain, but I keep trying to learn! I hope the tool helps, it certainly did me :0)

Answer (score 0):

In this block:

```
if number > 1: 
    print_numbers(number-1) 
print(number)
```

the interpreter enters the `print_numbers` function under that condition, but will *afterwards* also print the number. Your expected effect would occur if you put the print in an else branch:

```
if number > 1: 
    print_numbers(number-1) 
else:
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is this:

1. call function: print_numbers(10)
2. call function: print_numbers(9)

etc. etc.

10. call function: print_numbers(1)

in print_numbers(1) there's no next function being called so the

```
if number > 1: 
    print_numbers(number-1)
```

is skipped. Now the print statement is called, your program prints '1'.

11. print_numbers(1) continues and prints 1
12. print_numbers(2) continues and prints 2

etc etc.

If you were to put the print statement earlier, like this:

```
def print_numbers(number): 
    print(number) 
    if number > 1: 
        print_numbers(number-1) 
print_numbers(10)
```

It would first print, and then call the function, returning 10, 9, 8, 7 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You read the instructions the wrong way…
In the body of the function, the order of the instructions is the following :

if the number is greater than one, the function calls a function and waits for its completion before printing the value. So, if print_numbers(10) is called :

- it calls print_numbers(9) and wait
- print_numbers(8) calls print_numbers(7) and wait
- print_numbers(7) calls print_numbers(6) and wait

…

- print_numbers(1) prints 1 and returns
- print_numbers(2) resumes, prints 1 and returns
- print_numbers(3) resumes, prints 1 and returns

…

- print_numbers(9) resumes, prints 1 and returns
- print_numbers(10) resumes, prints 1 and returns

Beware, the `print` statement have the same indentation as the `if` statement. Si the `if block` is called and after that, the execution continues with the `print` statement.